# PostgreSQL 10 => 11.1 pg_upgrade Postmaster Using Old Cluster

Tags: postgresql, pg-upgrade, pg-ctl

I seem to be caught between two operations, both `pg_upgrade` to change over the `PostgreSQL` major version, and `pg_ctl` to control the current postmaster control of the `old cluster`.

```
[Sun Dec 30 09:29 rich@HQ /usr/local/var] /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin/pg_upgrade -v \
>     -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin \
>     -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.1/bin \
>     -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old \
>     -D /usr/local/var/postgres
Running in verbose mode
"/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/usr/local/var/postgres.old" -o "-p 50432 -c autovacuum=off -c autovacuum_freeze_max_age=2000000000  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1

There seems to be a postmaster servicing the old cluster.
Please shutdown that postmaster and try again.
Failure, exiting
```

I've tried to rename `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.pid` and that didn't solve anything.  Docs say I can use `pg_ctl` to shut down the postmaster, but that isn't working:

```
[Sun Dec 30 09:44 rich@HQ ~] pg_ctl --pgdata=/usr/local/var/postgres start -m fast
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
waiting for server to start....2018-12-30 09:44:33.541 EST [12042] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2018-12-30 09:44:33.541 EST [12042] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 10, which is not compatible with this version 11.1.
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

So I can't upgrade the version without shutting down the postmaster, and shutting down the postmaster requires initialization of the new version.  I'm caught.  Any insight appreciated as to how I can get `11.1` working.

**UPDATE**

The update log said the following after trying to deal with the old version:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    pg_upgrade run on Tue Jan  1 21:22:45 2019
-----------------------------------------------------------------

command: "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/usr/local/var/postgres.old" -o "-p 50432 -c autovacuum=off -c autovacuum_freeze_max_age=2000000000  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib
    Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin/postgres
    Reason: image not found
no data was returned by command ""/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin/postgres" -V"
The program "postgres" is needed by pg_ctl but was not found in the
same directory as "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin/pg_ctl".
Check your installation.


[Tue Jan 01 21:23 rich@HQ /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin] ll
total 18960
drwxr-xr-x  38 rich  admin   1.3K Dec 28 17:01 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 rich  admin   476B Dec 28 16:56 ..
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    51K Nov 16 04:56 clusterdb
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    55K Nov 16 04:56 createdb
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    59K Nov 16 04:56 createuser
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    51K Nov 16 04:56 dropdb
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    51K Nov 16 04:56 dropuser
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   789K Nov 16 04:56 ecpg
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   113K Nov 16 04:56 initdb
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    30K Nov 16 04:56 oid2name
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    26K Nov 16 04:56 pg_archivecleanup
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   102K Nov 16 04:56 pg_basebackup
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    30K Nov 16 04:56 pg_config
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    38K Nov 16 04:56 pg_controldata
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    52K Nov 16 04:56 pg_ctl
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   351K Nov 16 04:56 pg_dump
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    92K Nov 16 04:56 pg_dumpall
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    51K Nov 16 04:56 pg_isready
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    65K Nov 16 04:56 pg_receivewal
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    70K Nov 16 04:56 pg_recvlogical
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    47K Nov 16 04:56 pg_resetwal
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   148K Nov 16 04:56 pg_restore
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    78K Nov 16 04:56 pg_rewind
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    26K Nov 16 04:56 pg_standby
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    31K Nov 16 04:56 pg_test_fsync
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    26K Nov 16 04:56 pg_test_timing
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   120K Nov 16 04:56 pg_upgrade
-rw-------   1 rich  admin   796B Dec 28 17:04 pg_upgrade_internal.log
-rw-------   1 rich  admin   358B Dec 28 17:04 pg_upgrade_server.log
-rw-------   1 rich  admin   358B Dec 28 17:04 pg_upgrade_utility.log
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    76K Nov 16 04:56 pg_waldump
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   122K Nov 16 04:56 pgbench
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   5.8M Nov 16 04:55 postgres
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rich  admin     8B Nov 16 04:55 postmaster -> postgres
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin   544K Nov 16 04:56 psql
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    59K Nov 16 04:56 reindexdb
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    64K Nov 16 04:56 vacuumdb
-r-xr-xr-x   1 rich  admin    30K Nov 16 04:56 vacuumlo
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53964771/905902

Comment: Yes, that is MY old question.  This is related, downstream, but a completely different question.

Comment: Yes, but in that case: why do you still use the **old** binary?

Comment: I'm not still using anything.  What __old__ are you referring to?  How about a suggestion?  There is no current process, as the database isn't running at all.  But the system tells me the postmaster isn't shut down for some reason and is viewing the old cluster...which isn't running.

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6/bin/pg_upgrade`  <<-- Should be the 11.x version.

Comment: Didn't catch that.  The 11.x version has the same reply about `postmaster servicing the old cluster, shut down postmaster and try again.`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgupgrade.html step#7

Comment: @wildplasser Found some new notes, should I update or post something new?

Comment: I gave up going to `11.1` and pinned `10.6`